# opencv flann module: knn-search for hierarchical kmeans tree giving weird result

Tags: opencv, sift, knn, flann

I have about 130,000 SIFT descriptors. I am building a hierarchical Kmeans-index using Opencv's flann module. After this I want to quantize these 130,000 descriptors (will quantize more later). I am using flann's knnsearch method for doing this. But the result of this method is something weird. For every descriptor the nearest index it is showing is the index of the descriptor itself. However, it should be displaying the cluster-ID of the nearest cluster which will be one of the leaves of the HIK-tree.

Should I try k=2

Here is a code snippet -

```
 int k=1;
 cv::flann::KMeansIndexParams indexParams(8,4,cvflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP) ;
 cv::flann::Index hik_tree(cluster_data, indexParams);
 Mat indices,dist;
 hik_tree.knnSearch(cluster_data, indices, dist, k, cv::flann::SearchParams(64));
```

Answer (score 2):

`knnSearch` is looking for the k-nearest neighbours in the index (it does not give the cluster-ID!). You build your index using `cluster_data`, and then you try to match `cluster_data` against itself. In this situation, it is not surprising that the closest neighbour to each descriptor is itself...

**EDIT:** If you want to get the centers, have a look at this (from the source of the FLANN library):

```
/**
 * Chooses the initial centers using the algorithm proposed in the KMeans++ paper:
 * Arthur, David; Vassilvitskii, Sergei - k-means++: The Advantages of Careful Seeding
 */
template <typename Distance>
class KMeansppCenterChooser : public CenterChooser<Distance>
{
...
```

Comment: then how can i get the closest cluster.Is the radiussearch method supposed to do it.i want to go till the leaf of the index

Answer (score 0):

k-NN is a supervised classification algorithm, that's why you are supposed to construct an `Index` object with your training samples, so use

> cv::flann::Index hik_tree(samples, indexParams);

instead of

> cv::flann::Index hik_tree(cluster_data, indexParams);